# ¿Que puedo hacer? SQLSERVER - The multi-part identifier "SUPER81_WEB.dbo.CONTROL_INVENTARIOS.codigo" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

Help

```
    SELECT CANTIDAD FROM SUPER81_2011.isplus.StockDiario
    WHERE STOCKDIARIO.CodProducto = SUPER81_WEB.dbo.CONTROL_INVENTARIOS.codigo;
```

```
Error: 
The multi-part identifier "SUPER81_WEB.dbo.CONTROL_INVENTARIOS.codigo" could not be bound.***
```

Comment: Qué puedes hacer? Poner el identificador correcto. O tal vez describir bien cuál es el objetivo de lo que quieres lograr, qué es lo que has intentado, cuál es la respuesta que esperas y cuál es el resultado que obtienes.

Comment: Tienes 1 tabla de SUPER81_2011 en el FROM pero en el WHERE haces referencia a otra bd llamada SUPER81_WEB. Quizá esto sea un typo

Answer (score 1):

Lo que el error dice básicamente es que no existe ningun campo, en la consulta, que pueda asociarse con el nombre `SUPER81_WEB.dbo.CONTROL_INVENTARIOS.codigo`.

Por un lado, todo lo que está al alcance de la consulta en las cláusula `select`, `where`, `order by`, etc, depende de lo que aparezca en la cláusula `from`.

En otras palabras, aunque exista un campo o valor en la estructura de la base de datos, ya sea en tablas, vistas, etc, no puedes referenciarlo en una consulta de selección, a menos que incluyas dicha tabla o vista en la cláusula `from` y la relaciones de alguna manera con el resto de las tablas/vistas que ya están en la consulta.

Por otro, los nombres de campos suelen calificarse solo con el nombre de la tabla o el alias que se le ha dado en el from. Es decir, `tabla.campo` o `alias.campo`, y no `servidor.basededatos.esquema.tabla`.

Eso te obliga a, por ejemplo, si usas varias tablas con el mismo nombre en el `from`, por ejemplo porque vienen de distintos esquemas o de distintas bases de datos, o incluso la misma tabla de la misma base de datos y esquema, a darles alias distintos en cada aparición.

Dado que no se conoce la estructura de tus bases de datos, ni lo que pretendes lograr, no sabría decirte la solución completa a tu problema, pero si quieres acceder a ese campo, no tienes de otra que incluir la tabla en el from, o bien, si ya tienes una fila de dicha tabla a través de otro proceso, proporcionar directamente el valor del campo, por ejemplo a través de una variable o parámetro, y no referenciarlo directamente en la sentencia.

La primera, sería algo como

```sql
select StockDiario.Cantidad
  from SUPER81_2011.isplus.StockDiario
       inner join SUPER81_WEB.dbo.CONTROL_INVENTARIOS on StockDiario.CodPRoducto = CONTROL_INVENTARIOS.Codigo
```

La segunda, por ejemplo:

```sql
declare variable @Codigo int;
select @Codigo = CONTROL_INVENTARIOS.Codigo
  from SUPER81_WEB.dbo.CONTROL_INVENTARIOS
 where CONTROL_INVENTARIOS.NombreProducto = 'Salsa Kerns 900g';

select CANTIDAD 
  from SUPER81_2011.isplus.StockDiario
 where STOCKDIARIO.CodProducto = @Codigo;
```

Como he dicho antes, estos son solo ejemplos basados en meras suposiciones. Con la explicación debieras tenerlo suficientemente claro para resolver el error que se te está presentando.

Comment: Estás usando `codigo` como tabla pero es una columna.

Comment: Gracias Luis, ya está corregido.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte. No quise poner otra respuesta porque me parece que la tuya estaba muy completa y podía corregirse.

Comment: Me pasa con frecuencia lo mismo con tus respuestas. Es más bien raro que escriba una si vos llegas primero. Un saludo. :)

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso, se producía el error por un foreign key que hacía referencia a una tabla inexistente (le había cambiado de nombre).